# str.join TypeError when decoding binary file using struct.unpack

Tags: python, unpack

I am updating code from Python 2.x to Python 3.9. The program reads a binary file and converts it to a csv. I am not sure how to adapt these lines:

```
readBytes = inputFile.read(4)                         # four bytes store an I16 on index 2&3. 0&1 are empty.
readBytes = ''.join([readBytes[2], readBytes[3]])
arg = "h"
number=struct.unpack('>' + arg, readBytes)[0]
```

This throws: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: ``readBytes = readBytes[2:4]`` should work. Note that ``readBytes[2]`` (and similar) returns the integer value of the byte – use slicing instead of indexing to get bytes.

Comment: This is the solution, thanks :)